# Type Mismatch when using + to concatenate

Tags: excel, vba

**The problem**

I just want to the A2 cell to say `Exam Mailers for (current month) (current year)`. Example: `Exam Mailers for April 2020`

if I do:

```
Range("a2").Value = "Exam Mailers for " + (months(i))
```

It works and I get

```
Exam Mailers for April
```

**BUT if I do:**

```
Range("a2").Value = "Exam Mailers for " + (months(i)) + " " + Year(Now)
```

it fails with

```
Run-time error `13`: Type mismatch
```

Here is the full code so far:

```
Sub datechange_1()
Dim months(11) As String
months(0) = "Janurary"
months(1) = "Feburary"
months(2) = "March"
months(3) = "April"
months(4) = "May"
months(5) = "June"
months(6) = "July"
months(7) = "August"
months(8) = "September"
months(9) = "October"
months(10) = "November"
months(11) = "December"

Dim nowMonth As Integer
nowMonth = Month(Now)

For i = 0 To 11
  If nowMonth = (i + 1) Then
     Range("a2").Value = "Exam Mailers for " + (months(i)) + " " + Year(Now)
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any ideas or suggests are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: change the `+` to `&`

Comment: You can use + to concatenate two strings, but if one of the arguments is a numeric type, you'll get a type error because VB will interpret the + operator as numeric addition instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Which is why you should immediately just switch to `&` for all concatenation (repeating ad nauseam I know).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be just Str(Year(Now)). Looks like should work.

Comment: OMG you can just Str() it like in python? hahaha that is awesome!! I am just learning vbscript so I don't know where to start. lol but now that I know it has Str() that will be awesome for me in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer! :(

Comment: `Str` in VBA is *not* the same as `str` in Python. `&` should be used to concatenate.

Comment: @JatonJustice - don't use `Str`. Change the `+` to `&`.

Comment: @BigBen Ah! Understandable. Thank you for explaining that and I will do that now! :)